# Implicit PendingIntent error from Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Google play with the title **Implicit PendingIntent**, said Your app contains an Implicit Internal Intent vulnerability.

*Implicit Internal Intent
Your app contains an Implicit Internal Intent vulnerability. Please see [this Google Help Center article](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/10399926) for details.
ir.com.jammer.jammers.PassiveJammerService.notifyFragment

*Implicit PendingIntent
Your app contains an Implicit PendingIntent vulnerability. Please see [this Google Help Center article](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/10437428) for details.
ir.ayyza.netguard.ServiceSinkhole$2$1.run

i have used standard package, how to fix this error?

Comment: Probably used in a library, if any

Comment: Use some alternate package maybe?